# How to click on a button based on its inner text? VB.Net

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I'm having an issue with a button i'm trying to click in a webbrowser and I can't seem to get it to work, after hours of googling I still can't get it to work.

Heres the HTML code:

```
<input class="btn btn_large btn_blue" type="submit" value="Login">
```

I just need to invoke a click on it or somehow simulate the pressing of the "Enter" key maybe?
Any help is greatly appreciated. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`GetElementsByTagName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
For i As Integer = 0 To wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").Count - 1
    Dim elem As HtmlElement = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")(i)

    If elem.GetAttribute("type") = "submit" _
    AndAlso elem.GetAttribute("value") = "Login" Then  
        elem.InvokeMember("click")
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

With `wb` being the `WebBrowser` control. `GetElementByTagName("input")` method retrieves all the HTML elements that are **input**, and then you can check each one. You can compare the *class* or the *value* only if there is no need for more.

You can compare the string with `.Equals()` to get better results (ignoring case for example):

```
elem.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd give it an ID so it's:

`<input id="submit" class="btn btn_large btn_blue" type="submit" value="Login">`

Then your JS is:

```
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function () { 
  /* do stuff here */ 
};
```

Comment: The issue is I cant give it an ID as I don't have access to the files on the website, I need to roll with what I have.